# Cubic spline coefficients in Matlab

Tags: matlab, spline

Suppose I have n data points (x(i),y(i)) with i=1,..,n. I want to compute a cubic interpolant that fits exactly these points (interpolation, not least squares fit). I can do the following in Matlab:

```
x_min = -1;
x_max = 1;
nx    = 10;
x = linspace(x_min,x_max,nx)';
y = exp(-x);
pp = csapi(x,y); %Can also use spline
disp(pp)

  form: 'pp'
breaks: [-1 -0.7778 -0.5556 -0.3333 -0.1111 0.1111 0.3333 0.5556 0.7778 1]
 coefs: [9×4 double]
pieces: 9
 order: 4
   dim: 1
```

This returns the coefficients in the matrix pp.coefs: each row l (for l=1,..,n-1) of this matrix gives the 4 coefficients of the cubic polynomial for the specific subinterval l. However, I would like the cubic spline written as follows

S(x) = sum of phi_j(x)*c(j)

where c is a vector of n coefficients and phi_j(x) is the j-th basis function evaluated at x, for j=1,..,n. How can I get these n coefficients, and, optionally the basis matrix Phi=[phi_1,phi_2,..,phi_n]? This is also useful if I need the derivative of the spline. The Matlab functions csapi and spline give an (n-1)*4 matrix of coefficients which is not what I want.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I am not sure whether I understand your expectation correctly. Splines are evaluated for intervals, so it is obvious that you get N-1 sets of coefficients, for each interval a set. What you want is a linear combination over the entire range? I am not an expert in this field, but my first guess would be, splines are not what you are looking for?

Comment: @Irreducible thanks! Actually any spline can be written as a linear combination of n basis function. For spline, the basis are non zero only over a small interval (e.g. for a linear spline at most two basis are non zero). For a global polynomial instead the basis are non zero over the entire domain

Comment: Please see this link that explains better what I mean: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-spline
I also attach the relevant part: any spline function can be written as a linear combination of basis functions:

Comment: I think I found how to do it, the key is to use the routine "spcol" in Matlab (curve fitting toolbox). Hopefully when I have some time I will post a complete answer